# Factors of an irreducible polynomial over $GF(2^8)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Prove that the irreducible polynomial $f(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$ for $GF(2^8) $

1. has no polynomial factors of degree 1
2. has no polynomial factors of degree 2
3. has no polynomial factors of degree 3
4. has no polynomial factors of degree 4

How would I go about proving this? I thought the fact that $f(x)$ is irreducible means that it has no factors...

Comment: I think they are asking you to **prove** that $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Is $GF(2^8)$ the field with $256$ elements?

Comment: Yes, I believe GF(2^8) has 256 elements. It's also shown as GF(256) in the book.